# How do I remove this PCB from another PCB?

Tags: pcb, amplifier

I'm trying to replace a transistor on this amplifier. I cannot remove this PCB for the life of me. Is there a secret here? It has these black connectors going into the bottom PCB. I've put a lot of force trying to lift it and anymore I feel like I will break it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Even if it can just pull out, and I'm not saying you can, something that long with connectors all along its length will jam if on one side if you pull it at any angle other than perfectly straight. You might need to build something to lever it out evenly. Not to mention that a single connector can be quite tight to begin with and when you have a lot of them that force can add up very quickly.

Comment: Think about it; how would a trained technician at the parent company get it out? The squarish latch you see on the connector holds the answer. Without breaking any, I think these can be pushed or manipulated somehow to get this board out. Use a small flat screwdriver and be gentle. Pull it apart as vertically as you can.

Answer (score 1):

I would work back and forth along the length of the PCB using a piece of bent steel like this blanking plate.  Slide the short end under the PCB then rock the tool sideways to lift the PCB a bit at a time.  Hopefully there is enough of a gap to fit it in, but it is hard to tell from the photos.

[image]